# Non repeating random number in c# for Mine sweeper Game

Tags: c#, .net

i am developing a mine sweeper game in c# of dimension (8 x 8).The difficulty levels increase/decrease the number of mines on the grid.

I use a random class (with min,max set;) to generate a random cell number.The problem i am facing is ,the random object keeps repeating the same number.I tried to resolve this issue by maintaining a local list where i store the generated unique random numbers.The next time i call Next(), i would check it against the local list ,to see if its already present.If the number is already present i would keep calling Next() until  i get a new number which is unique and not present in the list.But this doesnt look in itself a good solution as sometimes it takes painful amount of time to generate a new list.

Any suggestions on this please

Comment: Need to see code. Most Minesweeper placement algorithms don't generate numbered squares - they generate mines and calculate the numbers based on the mine positions.

Comment: You're probably creating a new instance of Random for ever number you generate...

Comment: Without seeing any code it's kind of hard to get the gist of things, but from what I can tell you have the following:

A multi-dimensional array [8][8] for the grid layout of the game, you're now trying to randomly place mines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a *shuffle* based on a fixed number of cells (8,8), e.g. a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). This would guarantee that any coordinate only appears exactly once (as opposed to repeatedly using Random.Next() where you can draw the same number many times), and the order of appearance of coordinates is randomized.

Initialize an array that contains all the coordinates of your cells, shuffle the array and maintain an index of the next "random" cell, return the cell at the offset of the index and increase the index.

Comment: i tried of a different way where in i shuffled an int[] array of 64 elements,with the value starting from 1 .. 64.i used the random class to pick two unique numbers(indices) and then i swapped the array elements a few times and then i took the first n elements(n = number of mines).Thanks for the suggestion i will have a look at this

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use the same random number generator, repeating values are possible.

One way to avoid this would be to generate a list of possible values and using the random number generated to access a value in this list (using as indice) and reducing this list, as you find places to put mines to.

For 8 X 8 example, you have 64 possible places

```
 List<int> possibleValues = new List<int>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
 {
     possibleValues[i] = i;
 }

List<int> result = new List<int>();

Random r = new Random();
int numberOfMines = 50; //say you want to put 50 mines there

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMines; i++)
{
    int indice = r.Next(possibleValues.Count);

    int value = possibleValues[indice];

    possibleValues.Remove(value);
    result.Add(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of picking slots where the mines should be, loop through the slots and calculate the probability that there should be a mine there. The implementation for this becomes very simple, as you just need a single loop:

```
bool[] mines = new bool[64];

int cnt = 12;
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < mines.Length; i++) {
  if (rnd.Next(mines.Length - i) < cnt) {
    mines[i] = true;
    cnt--;
  }
}
```

(Room for improvement: You can exit out of the loop when `cnt` reaches zero, if you don't need to initialise all slots.)

Answer (score 1):

First calculate the number of mines, and empty fields.

```
Random rand=new Random();
int mines=GetMinesFromDifficulty(...);
int empty=TotalFields-mines;
```

Then for each field:

```
for(int y=0;y<height;y++)
  for(int x=0;y<height;y++)
  {

    if(random.Next(mines+empty) < mines))
    {
      field[x,y]=Mine;
      mines--;
    }
    else
    {
      field[x,y]=Empty;
      empty--;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your grid is 8x8, and you want to randomly choose an unused cell instead of pulling random numbers until you hit an unused one, then keep track of the number of unused cells. Say 8 have been used, leaving 55 unused. Then generate a random number between 0 and 54. You would then have to count through, and find the nth empty cell.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to think of the problem in a more linear way. Instead of say a 2D array... Squares[8][8] think of it as a single dimension array Squares[64].

At this point you generate a number between 0-63 for your random mine placement. If say the value is 10 you could store for later to offset subsequent numbers. You can reduce your range now from 0-62, if you pulled out the value 16 you would want to add +1 for each value you'd already pulled out underneath it (so actually use 17 in this case, but square 10 has been excluded from our set).

Answer (score -1):

Without seeing any code it's kind of hard to get the gist of things, but from what I can tell you have the following:

A multi-dimensional array [8][8] for the grid layout of the game, you're now trying to randomly place mines?

You'll need to keep one instance of Random for generating the numbers, else you will get the same number over and over again. Something like this

```
private readonly Random randomNumber = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(this.randomNumber.Next(1, 10));
}
```

This will then generate 10 random numbers, each one different.

Comment: They're not guaranteed to be different... there is just an attempt to provide an even distribution over the set.

Comment: Good point, the OP could store the numbers generated in this method into an array and then each number to see if it already exists.

Comment: @LukeBerry: The OP said, that he uses a local list to fix the problem, but the solution is to slow. He asked for an alternative solution.